# Run ubuntu applications from windows

Tags: windows

I am wondering if there is a way to run Ubuntu applications from Windows. I have heard of WINE, which emulates Windows in order to run Windows applications on Ubuntu. Is their a Windows application that would allow you to run Ubuntu applications on Windows?

Comment: I suggest you install Ubuntu in a VM in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general question to this is **NO**, however, there is a *but*:

- Some applications are cross-platform so you can find their Windows versions. For example, there's [KDE for Windows initiative](http://windows.kde.org/) which supposedly allows you to run KDE programs on Windows
- Mostly for command-line programs, there's a compatibility layer called [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
- you can run Ubuntu programs in a virtual machine in Windows.

But generally you can not take an arbitrary .deb and install and run it in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There's also Xwindows, which would allow you to run applications from the Ubuntu server on your windows desktop. It can take a little setting up - the key is to understand that -you- are the server and the Ubuntu server is contacting you - but once it's set up I think it will do what you're looking for.

Check out Google for XMing, that's a classic XWindows solution. Cygwin has XWin support as well. I think it will meet your needs.